# r convert different datetime formats in 1 column of a data frame

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am struggling with the following. I need to import multiple .csv files from multiple directories and append them in a data frame. I figured out how to do this using `dir()` and `lapply`. Here's a resulting example:

```
    structure(list(datetime = c("11/05/14 13:00", "11/05/14 13:30", 
"11/05/14 14:00", "11/05/14 14:30", "11/05/14 15:00", "02/08/12 08:32", 
"02/08/12 08:52", "02/08/12 09:12", "02/08/12 09:32", "02/08/12 09:52"
), file = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), .Names = c("datetime", "file"))

         datetime file
1  11/05/14 13:00    1
2  11/05/14 13:30    1
3  11/05/14 14:00    1
4  11/05/14 14:30    1
5  11/05/14 15:00    1
6  02/08/12 08:32    2
7  02/08/12 08:52    2
8  02/08/12 09:12    2
9  02/08/12 09:32    2
10 02/08/12 09:52    2
```

Above, datetime is a character object and file integer. I wish to convert datetime to POSIXct. Now the issue that I am facing is that the date in the first file is dd/mm/yy, and mm/dd/yy in the second file. How can I tell R to convert all dd/mm/yy and mm/dd/yy formats into posixct (yyyy/mm/dd) without confusing dates that have a meaning in both formats? i.e. 11/05/14 13:00 should be converted to 2014-05-11 13:00:00, and 02/08/12 08:32 should become 2012-02-08 08:32:00. To be clear, there is only 1 format within a file, but multiple formats between files.

I tried to use `lubridate` package using a solution found somewhere online. I realised however that this solution does not discriminate between formats and just converts whatever it can. Below is my script.

```
all_csv = dir(dir, recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE, pattern="\\.csv$")
    myfiles = lapply(all_csv, read.csv,sep=sep,dec=dec,stringsAsFactor=F,header=F,skip=2)

for(i in 1:length(myfiles)){
            library(lubridate)     
            mdy_hms1 <- mdy_hms(myfiles[[i]]$datetime, tz="US/Eastern")            
            dmy_hms1 <- dmy_hms(myfiles[[i]]$datetime, tz="US/Eastern")
            dmy_hms1[is.na(dmy_hms1)]<-mdy_hms1[is.na(dmy_hms1)]
            myfiles[[i]]$time<-dmy_hms1
    }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is there any pattern, i.e. do you know which rows have which formats? You could then subset the desired rows and apply specific formatting only to the preselected rows.

Comment: No there is no pattern unfortunately. Files are of varying lenghts, which depends on sampling interval and duration of recording (which are not specified here).

Comment: Than is there a way to decide which rows are using which formats? You can guess that if `xx>12` than it's `dd/mm` but there has be a more robust way for dates `01/01/12`. To me, the problem boils down to that aspect. If you can figure that out it will be matter of applying proper formats to selected rows.

Comment: There should be a way, if you go through the file and there is at least one date where `xx > 12` then it's `dd/mm/yy` so for all the lines in the file (which could be used as row numbers in your table), you apply this format, I would say. This won't be fool proof (as there may be file with days < 12 but in a format *dd/mm* but would get you closer to the desired solution, I think.

Comment: Yes I think the solution can be found here. key is to have R search the entire column and base its decision over the maximum xx/mm/yy. I think it will be foolproof datetimes will go on for a minimum of 3 months, so there will be a value that exceeds 12.

Comment: @Konrad: I found the solution thanks to you, see answer. Thanks again

Comment: I'm glad to read that the discussion was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who try to achieve something similar, try use `strsplit()`. This allows you to extract date and time components and then use 2 if loops for when the extracted value <=12 or >12.

```
threshold <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(myfiles[[1]]$time), '/'), function(x) x[1])

if(max(threshold) > 12){
      dmy_hms1 <- dmy_hms(myfiles[[i]]$time, tz=TZ)
      myfiles[[i]]$time<-dmy_hms1 # overwrite existing time column
    }

if(max(threshold) <=12){
  mdy_hms1 <- mdy_hms(myfiles[[i]]$time, tz=TZ)
  myfiles[[i]]$time<-mdy_hms1 # overwrite existing time column
}
```